# How to split large style file (qss file) in QT to small file and load them all

Tags: qt, split, qt4.8, qtstylesheets

What I am trying to do I need to split my large style file to small style files
because now it is hard to read the style file(qss file) and add new styling to it.
after that i need to load those small qss files to apply them all

I am loading my Big file by calling function on main I have created

```
void Utilities::loadEnglishStyle()
{
    QFile file(":/EnglishClasses.qss");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
    qApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
    file.close();
}
```

I thought about split the big file, add the small files to the resources, open all of them by `QFile` and after that concatenate them all in one string
but every time when adding new qss file i still need to do the same process again

Is there any efficient way to do this ?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds correct. The process is not as complex as it sounds. The only thing you need is to add the "smaller" qss file in the resources, under a specific prefix (eg. `stylesheets`), and then automatically load and concatenate all these files. Sample code follows:

```
QDir stylesheetsDir(":/stylesheets");
QFileInfoList entries = stylesheetsDir.entryInfoList();
QString completeStylesheet = "";
foreach (QFileInfo fileInfo, entries)
{
    QFile file(":/stylesheets/" + fileInfo.fileName(););
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
       continue;

    QTextStream in(&file);
    completeStylesheet += in.readAll()
}
```

Comment: it seems it is the optimal solution, i hoped there would be some functionality to just add the files to style collection without looping or something similar, what ever thanks for help you gave me a little hint

Answer (score 0):

you means some API shoud add as:

```
QWidget::addStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
QWidget::clearStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
```

Comment: but actually For the whole application not just for some widget